# Error "Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema" al intentar cargar base de datos Android Room desde assets

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Estoy intentando cargar una base de datos pre-empaquetada en mi aplicación Android mediante `createFromAsset()`.

He creado en principio una base de datos con una sola tabla para probar, pero me está dando error.

Tengo el siguiente código:

### Módulo (estoy usando HIlt)

```
@Provides
@Singleton
TestDatabase provideMovieDatabase(Application application){
    return Room.databaseBuilder(application, TestDatabase.class, "liturgia")
            .createFromAsset("liturgia.db")
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build();
}
```

### Dao

```
@Dao
public interface SalmoDao {

    @Insert
    void insert(Salmo salmo);

    @Query("DELETE From lh_salmo WHERE id_salmo = :idSalmo")
    void delete(int idSalmo);

    @Query("DELETE FROM lh_salmo")
    void clearSalmos();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM lh_salmo")
    LiveData<List<Salmo>> getAllSalmos();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM lh_salmo WHERE id_salmo = :idSalmo ")
    LiveData<Salmo> getSalmoById(int idSalmo);

}
```

### Entidad

```
@Entity(tableName = "lh_salmo")
public class Salmo {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name="id_salmo")
    private Integer idSalmo;
    private String salmo;

    public Salmo(Integer idSalmo, String salmo) {
        this.idSalmo = idSalmo;
        this.salmo = salmo;
    }

    public Integer getIdSalmo() {
        return idSalmo;
    }

    public void setIdSalmo(Integer idSalmo) {
        this.idSalmo = idSalmo;
    }

    public String getSalmo() {
        return salmo;
    }

    public void setSalmo(String salmo) {
        this.salmo = salmo;
    }

}
```

La base de datos que intento cargar tiene esta estructura:

```
CREATE TABLE `lh_salmo` 
( 
    `id_salmo` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    `salmo` TEXT 
)
```

Y he puesto el archivo `liturgia.db` en el directorio `assets` del proyecto.

Al compilar tengo el error siguiente:

> 2021-06-20 18:30:54.736 28136-28286/com.example.miapp
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: arch_disk_io_0
> Process: com.example.cinewatch, PID: 28136
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data.
> at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:92)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: lh_salmo(com.example.miapp.db.Salmo)...

```
Expected:

TableInfo{
  name='lh_salmo', 
  columns={
            id_salmo=Column{name='id_salmo', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, 
            salmo=Column{name='salmo', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}
          }, 
            foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
Found:

TableInfo{
  name='lh_salmo', 
  columns={
            salmo=Column{name='salmo', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
            id_salmo=Column{name='id_salmo', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}
          }, 
            foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

> at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onCreate(RoomOpenHelper.java:82) at
> androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onCreate(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
> at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:411)
> at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:316)
> at
> androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:92)
> at
> androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:53)
> at
> androidx.room.SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.java:90)
> at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:476) at
> androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:281)
> at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:324) at
> androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.java:83) at
> com.example.miapp.db.SalmoDao_Impl$5.call(SalmoDao_Impl.java:160) at
> com.example.miapp.db.SalmoDao_Impl$5.call(SalmoDao_Impl.java:157) at
> androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:90)
> ... 3 more

Comparando `Expected` y `Found` la diferencia sustancial que veo es que cambia el orden en que reconoce las columnas, no sé por qué. Luego cambian algunas configuraciones de los valores nulos y lo relativo a `affinity`.

¿Qué debo cambiar para que me reconozca la base de datos?

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a la herramienta [Room SQLite Difference Finder](https://hrankit.github.io/RoomSQLiteDifferenceFinder/) pude encontrar el problema.

En la clase de entidad, había anotado la columna `id_salmo` con `@NonNull`, he quitado esa anotación y el problema ha quedado resuelto:

```
@Entity(tableName = "lh_salmo")
public class Salmo {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name="id_salmo")
    private Integer idSalmo;
    private String salmo;

    // ...
}
```